# Find a pattern and modify the next line without modifying the other contents in the file. preferably linux based commands (sed, awk etc)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this:

```
# Hello, welcome to the world
# Trying to modify XXXXXX
# Some more random text

poly RANDOM LAYER{
    20 25
    18 2
    1 5
    1 2
    5 6
    }


poly RANDOM LAYER{
    30 50
    14 25
    15 25
    15 26
    15 26
    15 27
    }
```

I would like to increment the values in the next line of poly RANDOM layer,say add 10 to the first number (20+10=30) and 20 to the next number (25+20=45). The rest of the contents should be the same:
This should be done for all the lines immediately after poly RANDOM LAYER

The output should look like:

```
# Hello, welcome to the world
# Trying to modify XXXXXX
# Some more random text

poly RANDOM LAYER{
    *30 45*
    18 2
    1 5
    1 2
    5 6
    }


poly RANDOM LAYER{
    *40 60*
    14 25
    15 25
    15 26
    15 26
    15 27
    }
```

Comment: If Ed's answer worked for you, it's a good idea to mark his answer as accepted. He deserves it for nutting out that awk command :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the specific leading white space is always 4 chars:

```
$ awk 'f{$1="    "$1+10; $2+=20; f=0} /RANDOM/{f=1} 1' file
# Hello, welcome to the world
# Trying to modify XXXXXX
# Some more random text

poly RANDOM LAYER{
    30 45
    18 2
    1 5
    1 2
    5 6
    }


poly RANDOM LAYER{
    40 70
    14 25
    15 25
    15 26
    15 26
    15 27
    }
```

otherwise use:

```
$ awk 'f{fmt=$0; gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"%s",fmt); $0=sprintf(fmt,$1+10,$2+20); f=0} /RANDOM/{f=1} 1' file
```

as that will just reproduce in your output WHATEVER leading, trailing, or inter-field white space you have in your input.

Comment: Clever way of putting dynamic spacing!!

Comment: More clever IMHO is `awk 'f{fmt=$0; gsub(/[^ ]+/,"%s",fmt); $0=sprintf(fmt,$1+10,$2+20)` but maybe a bit TOO clever for this case :-). I do like the idiom of turning the original record into a format string by just replacing all non-blanks with a `%s` though - comes in very useful at times!

Comment: I wasn't even aware of such idiom. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Works great! However, the modified numbers are a tab space away from the other numbers. Just need to add a tab to bring those numbers in the same column as others.

Comment: I don';t see any tabs in your original file and the solution I posted doesn't use tabs at all so idk what you're referring to. If you need help figuring out a solution, let me know and provide some info on where there are tabs in your input file. I just updated my answer with a solution that will simply use in the output whatever white space you already use in the input.

Comment: @jaypal - turns out we need that idiom now too. Didn't see that coming!

Comment: @EdMorton I think I will just make an `awk` cookbook out of your Q&A and retire.

Comment: Not quite the same semantics, but `awk 'f{...sprintf(...)} {f=/RANDOM/} 1` is a nice touch.  (Saves the `f=0` assignment)

Comment: @WilliamPursell - nice! Next round of golf I'm all over that :-).

Answer (score 1):

You say (sed, awk, etc).  Is **perl** part of *etc*?

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+10/ge if($lastLineMatch); $lastLineMatch = m/poly RANDOM/; ' < file
```

Or if you want to add different values to the two numbers:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)/($1+10).$2.($3+20)/ge if($lastLineMatch); $lastLineMatch = m/poly RANDOM/; ' < file
```